# Why the trigger is not fired?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a `TextBlock` in my XAML that's configured with a trigger to activate when the user enters incorrect credentials. Here's the **XAML** snippet:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorMessage}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Medium"
           FontFamily="Montserrat" Foreground="Red" Margin="0,15,0,0">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowErrorAnimation,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" From="0" To="10" Duration="0:0:5" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="3x"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

In this XAML code, the `DataTrigger` is **bound** to the `ShowErrorAnimation` property from the `LoginViewModel`. When this property is set to true, the **trigger** should activate, and the associated **animation** should run. Here's the relevant code from the LoginViewModel:

```
public class LoginViewModel: ViewModelBase {

    // Other ViewModel code...

    private String _errorMessage;
    private bool _showErrorAnimation;
    public string ErrorMessage {
      get => _errorMessage;
      set {
        _errorMessage = value;
        onPropertyChanged(nameof(ErrorMessage));
      }
    }
    public bool ShowErrorAnimation {
      get => _showErrorAnimation;
      set {
        _showErrorAnimation = value;
        onPropertyChanged(nameof(ShowErrorAnimation));
      }
    }

    public LoginViewModel() {
      userRepository = new UserRepository();

      LoginCommand = new ViewModelCommand(ExecuteLoginCommand, CanExecuteLoginCommand);
      RecoverPasswordCommand = new ViewModelCommand(p => ExecuteRecoverPasswordCommand("", ""));
      ShowPasswordCommand = new ViewModelCommand(ExecuteShowPasswordCommand, CanExecuteShowPasswordCommand);
      RememberPasswordCommand = new ViewModelCommand(ExecuteRememberPasswordCommand, CanExecuteRememberPasswordCommand);
    }

    private void ExecuteLoginCommand(object obj) {
      bool isUserValid = userRepository.AuthenticateUser(new NetworkCredential(Username, Password));

      if (isUserValid) {
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(Username), null);
        IsViewVisible = false;
      } else {
        ErrorMessage = "Invalid user name or passwords";
        _showErrorAnimation = true;
      }

      // Other ViewModel code...
    }
```

I'm interested in understanding the reason behind the **trigger** not being activated, which is resulting in the absence of the shaking animation for the **text**.

Comment: Be aware that `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the DataTrigger Binding are pointless. A DataTrigger is inherently OneWay, and UpdateSourceTrigger only affects TwoWay and OneWayToSource Bindings.

Comment: Thank you I did not know it is only one way direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely due to the fact that you did not set an instance of TranslateTransform to the RenderTransform property.
Demo example:

```xml
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=cBox}">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked}"
                                    Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                                        From="0" To="10" Duration="0:0:5"
                                                        AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="3x"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <CheckBox x:Name="cBox" Content="Click Me"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Some Text" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Medium"
                    FontFamily="Montserrat" Foreground="Red" Margin="0,15,0,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Some Text" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Medium"
                    FontFamily="Montserrat" Foreground="Red" Margin="0,15,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>

    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you I have updated the XAML code and added the instance of TranslateTransform, and I also had to update the view model and change the `_showErrorAnimation` to `ShowErrorAnimation`